# Find objects with field value (this is a pointer)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have class say 'inspection' and there is a field name property (this is a pointer) . I am trying to retrieve a record by field value but getting nothing as a result. I am using following code

```
getInspectionByProperty = function(req) {
    console.log(req.body.propertyId)
            var query = new Parse.Query("Inspection");
            query.include('property');
            query.equalTo('property', req.body.propertyId);
            query.find({
              success: function(data) {
                    console.log('in success'); 
                    console.log(data);
                // Successfully retrieved the object.
              },
              error: function(error) {
                console.log('in error')
                console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
              }
             });
    };
```

I am getting this error in parse log

> Error: 102 pointer field property needs a pointer value

How can i get the record .Thanks in advance

Comment: You're trying to pass it an objectId while it expects an actual ParseObject. You probably have to pass the property object rather than the objectId. If you do have a property object, try to fetch it first by objectId and in the succes of the fetch, fetch the inspection that belongs to the property. I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what i try and thats work for me.

```
getInspectionByProperty = function(req) {
console.log(req.body.propertyId)
        var query = new Parse.Query("Inspection");
        query.include('property');
        query.equalTo("property", {
                    "__type": "Pointer",
                    "className": "Property",
                    "objectId": propertyId
                    });
        query.find({
          success: function(data) {
                console.log('in success'); 
                console.log(data);
            // Successfully retrieved the object.
          },
          error: function(error) {
            console.log('in error')
            console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
          }
         });
};
```